# Unity not finding scripts in folder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, namespaces

I just opened a Unity project that was functioning yesterday, only to get an error:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'X' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The error is called when another script `Y` tries to extend a class defined in `X`:

```
public class Y: X
{...}
```

Both X.cs and Y.cs are in the same folder.

The project ran/compiled with no problems yesterday. Since then I have rebooted the machine, but no other changes were made. I have tried deleting the Library folder with no success.

Unity v# 2020.3.33f1, I am using visual studio code as an editor.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please show actual code or reproducible issue. From this it’s hard to tell

Comment: If `X` is a `MonoBehaviour` or `ScriptableObject` then make sure it file name is exactly `X.cs`

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestions:**

> First check if the class name and the file name is same (which is obvious to check ofcourse)
>
> > secondly reimport the vs code pacakge from package manager and restart unity and vs code hope fully it will fix the problem if not then last step would be to check if by accident or willingly you have put the 'X' class inside a namespace and not mentioned that namespace where you trying to inherit in 'Y' class, but most probably I think second option should fix it.